# How do I serialize in binary an object that has a member a list of another objects in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display the data after deserialization and instead of the values inside the list, I get:
`System.Collections.Generic.List<ProiectPAWVlad.Sofer>` (sofer is the class)

I've tried this method:

```
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("fisier.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryFormatter bf2 = new BinaryFormatter();

Ruta r = new Ruta();
Sofer s=new Sofer();
Masina m=new Masina();

List<Sofer> soferi = new List<Sofer>();
List<Masina> masini = new List<Masina>();

soferi.Add(s);
masini.Add(m);

Transporturi t2 = new Transporturi(r, soferi,masini, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

bf2.Serialize(fs2, t2);
```

The binary serialization cannot convert list?

Comment: You might want to read this, and keep in mind this is official MS guidance. While the article is mainly in the context of ASP.Net, the reasoning applies to other .Net platforms as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete

Comment: Are you deserialising using the same types as when you serialised? Binary serialisation requires you to use the same types on both sides (i.e. the producer and consumer will need to reference a shared library that contains the types used by your objects). Can you please include your dwserialisation code plus the definition of your `Transporturi` class? Also, as referenced by Joel above, this method of serialisation should probably be avoided!

Comment: Firstly: don't use binary formatter; it is actively dangerous (it can be exploited), plus it is brittle. It *will* hurt you - the only questions are when and how. Binary serialization i.e. "writing a non-text file": fine; there are many safe choices - I'm biased but I'd suggest protobuf-net; easy to configure in most cases, but hard to give an example without seeing your types. As for "display the data after deserialization": you should get an identical graph back. Are you not? What are you seeing? We can't run your code without the types, so: we can only guess

Comment: Also: what code are you using to display it? Is this just a `.ToString()` confusion? The default `ToString()` of types, including collections, is to display the type name.